# Merge two collections in mongodb aggregation based on a value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

Have two collections

```
contact_details :

{_id:ObjectId("abcd1234"),
name:"elmaro",
email:"elmaro@gmail.com"}
```

```
loaction_details:

{_id:ObjectId("aasd234gas"),
contact_id:ObjectId("abcd1234"),
location:"Ohio"}
```

how to use aggregate function to transform data into this

Merged_data:

```
{contact_id:ObjectId("abcd1234"),
location:"Ohio",
name:"elmaro",
email:"elmaro@gmail.com"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operator to join `contact_details` and `loaction_details` collections and `$project` to transform the result.

```
db.contact_details.aggregate([
    {$lookup:{
         from:"loaction_details",
         localField:"_id",
         foreignField:"contact_id",
         as : "location"
     }},
     {$unwind:"$location"},
     {$project:{
         _id:0,
         name:1,
         email:1,
         contact_id:"$location.contact_id",
         location:"$location.location"
      }}
])
```

Comment: This will work fine if there is a document available in **location_details** collection for every document exist in **contact_details** collection. Otherwise, you should use $unwind with **preserveNullAndEmptyArrays** option. If there is any document that doesn't have a match in **location_details** then after unwinding the array, this option will preserve that document within the result. Otherwise, such documents will be skipped from the result.